# can I automatically define tkinter widgets using a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label, tkinter-entry

In the next code `categories` is a list. The code makes a window and adds labels and entry for each item on the list.

```py
class Win3():
                def __init__(self, master, categories):
                                self.master = master
                                self.master.geometry('400x250')
                                self.master.resizable(False,False)
                                self.frame = Frame(self.master)
                                self.frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)
                                y=0
                                for x in categories:
                                                Label(self.frame, bg='#92DBE9' ,width=15 ,text=x).grid(row=y,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)
                                                Entry(self.frame, bd=1, width = 20).grid(row=y,column=2, padx=2,pady=2)
                                                y+=1
```

How can I define the labels so I can define the labels and entries like `label1`, `entry1` `label2`, `entry2`,...
I want to use this so I can still change the text from the label or the insert after creating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "define the labels and entries like label1, entry1 label2, entry2". The names are irrelevant. You can save them as elements in a dictionary or list.

```
labels = []
entries = []
for x in categories:
    label = Label(self.frame, bg='#92DBE9' ,width=15 ,text=x)
    entry = Entry(self.frame, bd=1, width = 20)

    label.grid(row=y,column=0,padx=2,pady=2)
    entry.grid(row=y,column=2, padx=2,pady=2)

    labels.append(label)
    entries.append(entry)

    y+=1
```

With that, you can now access the labels with something like `labels[0]`, `labels[1]`, and so on. Likewise with the entries.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bryan! It works and your explanation is very helpful!